# Get function name in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, reflection

I am looking to get the name of function in swift.

I basically want something like

```
__FUNCTION__
```

but from a different function e.g.

```
func do () {
   code etc
}

func doStuff () {
   var funcName = do().name
}
```

the above would be perfect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please explain the use case? Why do you need that?

Comment: One use case is runtime generated and compiled code. Being able to get a function name at runtime allows for more compile-time checks.

Answer (score 26):

`#function` might be what you want.

```
print(#function)

class Log {
    func info(_ info: String, funcName: String = #function) {}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In Swift 3 the right keyword is *#function*. You could pass a pointer to a *String* object which is used to store the function name. For example:

```
func myFunction(param1:Any, param2:Any, functionName: UnsafeMutablePointer<String>?) -> Any {
    if functionName != nil { 
        functionName.pointee = #function 
    }
    ...
}
```

Usage:

```
var name:String 
// You can always pass nil if you are not interested in retrieving the 
// function name
let result = myFunction(1, 2, functionName: &name) 
print(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest, but it works.

```
func dost () -> (name: String,String) {
    return (__FUNCTION__,"")
}

func doStuff () {
    var funcName = dost().name
}
```

You could aways just return the function name without the tuple.

Comment: I arrived at something similar 

`func dostuff(getName: Bool) -> String {if (getName) return __FUNCTION__ 
}` 

but I was wondering if there was something nicer maybe

Comment: Note: in Swift 3 it has been replaced with #function.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Thanks! If you make your comment to an answer, it could be accepted, and the question could be closed.

Comment: Ok I elaborated it a bit and made it an answer.