# number of methods and variables in a class Swift iOS

Tags: java, ios, swift, reflection

How to get number of methods and variables in a class Swift iOS like reflection in Java. Something like `getDeclaredMethods()` and `getDeclaredFields()`.

```
getDeclaredMethods()       //will return array of methods defined.
getDeclaredFields()        //will return array of variables defined.
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the `Mirror(reflecting: Any)`and then loop through the `mirror.children`

This however wont tell you any information about the functions inside it. the child only contains the variable names and values.

i guess [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51199156/4757272) will be a sufficient answer tho.